# Referring item indexes one after the other

Tags: jquery

Any other way of writing this?

```
$("#list option:eq(24), #list option:eq(10),
 #list option:eq(26)")
.attr("selected", "selected");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("#list option").filter(function (index) {
    return index == 10 || index == 24 || index == 26;
}).attr("selected", "selected");
```

Or this:

```
$("#list option").filter(":eq(10), :eq(24), :eq(26)")
    .attr("selected", "selected");
```

Untested, so handle with care.

Comment: "Easier" was not asked for. But this method might be faster due to a smaller query expression.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
$("#list option").filter(function(val, i) {
    return [10,24,26].indexOf(i) + 1;
}).attr("selected", "selected");
```